# Can't append html element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am trying to get jquery to append text to a div element. I was trying to follow this link http://api.jquery.com/append/ but it's not working for me, All I see is Hello, but the words test do not get appended.

Here is the html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="test.js"></script>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="inner">Hello</div>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the test.js, it resides in the same directory as test.html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.inner').append("<p> Test </p>");
});
```

And here is the node server that serves the html page.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require('http');

var page = fs.readFileSync('test.html');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {  
  if(req.method == 'GET' || req.url == '/') {
    res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(page);
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: Open the console (F12) and check for errors ?

Comment: And you don't have a static route for the javascript file, which is probably the issue, static files aren't being served.

Comment: The console says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < test.js:1` but there is no `<` on line one of test.js

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't put the scripts in your head (or right before the closing tag)?

Comment: Nope, you're serving the .html file for all request, so if you look at the source for `test.js` you'd see the same HTML document

Comment: Install express, follow the guides on how to set up a static routes etc.

Comment: I am already, but I am also trying to understand your third comment.

Comment: Well, open the console and look at the error, on the right side in the console where you see the filename you can probably click it and see the content of the file. Node.js doesn't serve static files by default, you need routes for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is good, but your node.js server only serves `test.html` at the path `/`. Only the files you explicitly send will be available to the browser, so the HTML page will not be able to load `test.js`. Add an `else if` for this file (and change the content-type):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require('http');

var page = fs.readFileSync('test.html');
var testjs = fs.readFileSync('test.js');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {  
  if(req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/') {
    res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(page);
    res.end();
  } else if(req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/test.js') {
    res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    res.write(testjs);
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(80);
```

Also note:

- the `||` is now `&&`, because previously *any* GET request would have
  satisfied the first condition.
- the `==` are now `===` – it's better practice to use `===`, or strict equality, in most situations, including this one. More [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/) if you're interested.

Comment: I tried your example but chrome complains that the file test.js is a script but it's header says it's a html file. `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/test.js"` Is there a content-type for javascript I searched but can't  find anything.

Comment: @2trill2spill whoops! the content type should be `application/javascript` for `.js` files. I've updated the answer

Comment: @2trill2spill wow. right in the face. `req.method === 'GET' || req.url === '/'` has `||`, the 'or' operator, so *any* GET request satisfies the first condition. change that to `&&`